# Parsing Multiple Apis in JSON

Tags: ios, json, parsing

I'm new to the wonderous world of Objective-C and XCode. I stumbled upon [this](http://www.appcoda.com/fetch-parse-json-ios-programming-tutorial/) tutorial recently, and I used the tutorial to work with some APIs from Steam. I first tried the tutorial with the GetPlayerItems method from Steam's Web API, and it worked out great. The problem I have now is, I want to link this API with another API (specifically the GetSchema API), so that I can get more information about a specfic person's item in their backpack. but I don't know how to implement by sticking with the same structure as used by the tutorial. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE** I have called both API functions (the GetSchema and GetPlayerItems), but the problem is that in the table view, each function gets called separately, when I want to have both functions run at the same time. Basically the first API gets loaded, and I get a list of numbers, then the second API loads, and the images come up, but the original numbers from the first API vanish and come up as (null). Any ideas on what I should do?

**UPDATE #2 I have solved my problem. Thank-you to everyone who helped.**

Comment: Note that JSON is JSON and pretty much stands alone.  How you use JSON with one API has no relationship to how you might use it with another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create operations queue and add operation to perform multiple api calling.

[Apple's doc here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html)

[A Good tutorial here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues)

[Another one here](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/02/16/cocoa-tutorial-nsoperation-and-nsoperationqueue/)

Here is another way

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // call your api function1 here
});

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // call your api function2 here
});

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // call your api function3 here
});
```

Comment: How would I implement that using the same structure and code that the tutorial uses. I don't want to completely change the code I have right now.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very broad. You're looking to interact with a REST api that serves multiple resources.
Whether or not you choose to use the library in the following tutorial, it will greatly expand your knowledge of RESTful services:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/13097/intro-to-restkit-tutorial